# change the color of the polyline in DirectionsRenderer

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

i've integrated a map and i want to display the route directions between two locations.
everything is working fine and the directions is displayed perfectly ,
but i want to change the color of the `Polyline` direction ,i've tried this code like the documentation says :

```
//polyline options
    var pOptions = {
            map: map,
            strokeColor: "#2249a3",
            strokeOpacity: 0.9 ,
            strokeWeight: 12,
            z-index: 99
    };
    logJava(polylineOptions);

    //directionsRenderer options
    var mDirectionsRendererOptions = {
            map: map,
            suppressMarkers: true,
            suppressInfoWindows: true,
            polylineOptions: pOptions
    };

    logJava(mDirectionsRendererOptions);

    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(mDirectionsRendererOptions);
```

but when i add this code , it stops the map , and it displays nothing, when i comment it , everything is working fine .

what is wrong with this code, and how to change the color of the polyline with **google maps javascript api v3** ?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 24, accepted):

At global declarations

```
var polylineOptionsActual = new google.maps.Polyline({
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 10
    });
```

At initialise

```
function initialize() {
   directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({polylineOptions: polylineOptionsActual});
```

Comment: i've tried it , it changes the color , but it seems that the wieght did'nt changed , and also , when i try to use the red color for example, or the green color , it displays always the black color ... any IDEAS ??

Comment: I thought I should add a note here, since it may help someone - when defining a color for the markers, you can use hex colors like 'AABBCC' , but when defining it for the route fill color, you need to use: '#AABBCC', otherwise it will not work in Internet Explorer and you'll get black color. At least it was so in IE8 where I tested.

Comment: Can you please explain how to update the color for direction after it's already rendered? I want to put direction and then if user select some option change the direction's color accordingly. If I just call setOptions nothing changes. Thanks

Comment: This didn't work for me until I added the `map` property to `polylineOptionsActual`. Might be useful for someone

Comment: see comment below, using polylineOptions instead of a Polyline Object solved it for me

Comment: Do you have a link to the documentation for this?

Comment: Would be nice to know the default styling

Answer (score 9):

In answer marked as resolved I see that object Polyline used for polylineOptions. In my case I use the next code

```
new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({ suppressMarkers: true, polylineOptions: { strokeColor: '#5cb85c' } });
```

The difference is that I assign **polylineOptions**, not **Polyline** object. Not sure it could be helpful, but decided to add these answer.

Comment: it did make a difference for me, thanks! using the Polyline, it only rendered the LAST part if I passed in multiple waypoints! using polylineOptions instead, it renders my full map. Thanks!

Comment: This works, except that I cannot change the color. The strokeColor property does not have any effect, it seems

Answer (score 4):

Using [setOptions(options:DirectionsRendererOptions)](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#DirectionsRenderer) makes code more readable. The coding would be:

At global level:

```
var directionsDisplay;
```

Inside `initialize()` method:

```
var polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
    strokeColor: '#C00',
    strokeOpacity: 0.7,
    strokeWeight: 5
    });
directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
directionsDisplay.setOptions({polylineOptions: polyline}); 
now directionDisplay can be used in any method with the custom poly line.
```

Answer (score 3):

@Seacat, after you update the directionsRenderer with the new polylineOptions, you have to re-render the directions response which is stored inside the renderer object..

```
directionsRenderer.setDirections(directionsRenderer.directions);
```