# Google Maps Driving Directions, change Stroke Color?

Tags: google-maps, stroke

I have something very similar to this example:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-simple

All I am trying to do it change the stroke of the line from one city to another city, which is currently a purple color?

I tried putting strokeColor in myOptions, but no luck:

```
      var myOptions = {
        zoom:1,
        strokeColor: "#000000",
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      }
```

Comment: Already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9311498/change-the-color-of-the-polyline-in-directionsrenderer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like that's supported without drawing your own line.

http://groups.google.com/group/google-maps-js-api-v3/browse_thread/thread/23d27531c01c1086/7cf9db34abcf4f12?lnk=gst&q=change+color+route+&pli=1

Comment: That is an old post,  it is exposed,  check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9311498/change-the-color-of-the-polyline-in-directionsrenderer

Comment: javram - that's good stuff.  That post is V3 and from a google guy... so I figured it was good to go.  Thanks for the update!

Answer (score 0):

You can use polylineOptions to change the color of the line

polylineOptions: {
                            strokeColor: '#0088FF', // red
                            strokeWeight: 4,
                            strokeOpacity: 0.6
                        },